# Cassandra in Docker unable to make directory on mounted volume

Tags: cassandra, docker

When I attempt to start the docker image tobert/cassandra from https://github.com/tobert/cassandra-docker I get the following error.  Can anyone explain what this error means?

```
 os.MkdirAll('/data/conf') failed: %!s(MISSING)
```

The command I am running is:

```
sudo docker run -v /data/cassandra:/data tobert/cassandra
```

I have created the directory /data/cassandra in my host os of RH Linux.  I have even opened up the permissions all the way to see if it was a permission issue.

```
drwxrwxrwx.  2 root root    6 Apr 10 12:10 cassandra
```

Comment: I can create the missing directory /data/cassandra/conf and it moves on.  But then later it tries to chown the stuff in it and it gets a permission denied.  Even though I opened up all the permissions.  I am starting to think this is still just a permission problem.

Comment: Have you looked at Al's guide? https://tobert.github.io/post/2014-06-26-cassandra-and-docker.html

Answer (score 0):

Is SELinux enabled? You're doing everything right so something else must be blocking mkdir. Please check your syslog (RHEL <= 6.x) or journalctl (RHEL 7).